# Most efficient way to find keys that meets a condition in an object

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {
  black: {
    s: {
      quantity: 0,
    },
    m: {
      quantity: 0,
    },
  },
  red: {
    s: {
      quantity: 10,
    },
    m: {
      quantity: 20,
    },
  }
}


//My solution:
function test(obj){
  const color = Object.entries(obj).find(([k, v]) => 
    Object.values(v).find(({quantity}) => quantity !== 0));

  const size = Object.entries(color[1]).find(([k,v]) => v.quantity !== 0);

  return [color[0], size[0]] //Output: ['red', 's']
}
```

How to write a function that return keys 'red' and 's' because quantity is !== 0? I don't like my solution, just looking for a nicer way to solve this.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: can you please show the mock desired data that you expect... it is hard to come up with a solution without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {black: {
s: {
  quantity: 0,
},
m: {
  quantity: 0,
}, },   red: {
s: {
  quantity: 10,
},
m: {
  quantity: 20,
},}}

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    
  const subResult = Object.entries(val).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
      if (!val.quantity) {
         return acc
      }
      return { ...acc, [key]: val }
  }, {})
 if (!Object.keys(subResult).length) return acc
 return {
     [key]: subResult
 }}, {})
```

The Result will be:

```
{ red: {
     m: { quantity: 20 }
     s: { quantity: 10 }
}
```